# Error converting parsing TIME dd.MM.yyyy', '12:00

Tags: java, parsing, date, time

I have time on device 11:34

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy', 'hh:mm");
Date date_current =  new Date();
Date date_start = null;
date_start = sdf.parse("12.03.2014, 12:00");// I PARSE THIS DATE!!!
```

RESULT IS :

**date_start**:
 **Wed Mar 12 00:00:00 Восточноевропейское время 2014**

BUT SHOULD BE:
**Wed Mar 12 12:00:00 Восточноевропейское время 2014**

HOW to solve it?

Comment: can you get solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get 24h format use `HH` not `hh`. In 12h format hours can be in rage `0`-`11`, which makes 12 overflow to `0`.

Use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy', 'HH:mm");
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html says it all :) OP: read the docs... they're useful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a look about patterns of Simpledatrformat. where it clearly shows `H` is for (0-23).

[Reference for Date Format Pattern Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html#datepattern)

so you should change your code like below.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy', 'HH:mm");
Date date_current =  new Date();
Date date_start = null;
date_start = sdf.parse("12.03.2014, 12:00");
System.out.println("now time is.." + date_start);
```

OR

Use this:

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 8);
System.out.println(date);
SimpleDateFormat simpDate;
simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
System.out.println(simpDate.format(date));
```

Thanks.. use above code to parse correctly!!

Answer (score 1):

use 24 hour date format
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy', 'HH:mm");