# SimpleDateFormat missing time

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a strange issue. The below code is executed in a while loop through a few times. Now, every so often, this sdf.parse returns 0s for the hours, minutes and seconds. An example of the dates look like this...

```
2014:3:7:8:0
2014:3:7:9:0
2014:3:7:10:0
2014:3:7:11:0
2014:3:7:12:0  * This returns 0's
2014:3:7:13:0
2014:3:7:14:0
```

Below is the code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:M:d:h:m");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date sTime = null;
try {
    sTime = sdf.parse(start);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error converting parsing TIME dd.MM.yyyy', '12:00](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346705/error-converting-parsing-time-dd-mm-yyyy-1200). Please search StackOverflow before posting. You would have found hundreds of code examples to compare to your code and find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `12` at hour position is getting read in 12h format, so it is the same as 0. Try `H` instead of `h` in pattern

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:M:d:H:m");
```

Comment: You are the man! Will accept as the answer in 8 minutes ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

'h' represents hour in 1-12 format. You should use 'H' (in upper case) instead if you want 0-23 format. Also you needn't explicitly set default time zone because by default it equals TimeZone.getDefault().